# What's the function of bootstrap.cache.php?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I am reading the code of Sylius, I know the classes in `bootstrap.cache.php` have been existed in other files,So I am confused about what's the function of `bootstrap.cache.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the Symfony standard edition that will compile the most commonly used classes per request into one file, such as the ones found in the HttpFoundation component.

Symfony uses PSR-0 class loading, ie. One class per file, so this bootstrap file will reduce the number of times the filesystem is accessed.

http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/performance.html#use-bootstrap-files